# Venmo - Braintree payment - Server Integration

Tags: php, ios, payment, braintree, venmo

Using Venmo Touch, I'd client side validation and post the encrypted credit card details to our application server.

Application server retrieves the params inside the post method, and posts the retrieved params to Braintree server.

```
<?php $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
'amount' => '10.00',
'credit_card' => array(
    'number' => $_POST['encrypted_card_number'],
    'expirationMonth' => $_POST['encrypted_expiration_month'],
    'expirationYear' => $_POST['encrypted_expiration_year']
),
'options' => array(
    'venmo_sdk_session' => $_POST['venmo_sdk_session']
)));?>
```

If we ignore the 'options' tag, payment is successful. **Upon introducing the 'options' array with element `venmo_sdk_session` Braintree server doesn't responds.**

I'd doubt the key spelling/case sensitive "venmo_sdk_session".

Comment: have you tried `'venmo_sdk_session' => Braintree_Test_VenmoSdk::getTestSession()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not within the code.

We need to enable Venmo Touch, Payment Method Verification on settings screen of Braintree site using our account.